# System.Text: JsonSerializer.Deserialize with generics

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to make sense of the documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

My goal is simply to load [DICOM/JSON](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part18/sect_F.4.html) using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer (dotnet 5.0). The steps are easy from C# to JSON:

```
private class DataElement<T>
{
  public string vr { get; set; }
  public List<T> Value { get; set; }
}
[...]
var dataset = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataset.Add("00100021", new DataElement<string>() { vr = "LO", Value = new List<string>(1) { "Hospital A" }});
dataset.Add("00201206", new DataElement<int>() { vr = "IS", Value = new List<int>(1) { 4 } });
dataset.Add("00101030", new DataElement<double>() { vr = "DS", Value = new List<double>(1) { 72.5 } });
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dataset, serializeOptions);
File.WriteAllBytes("ds.json", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
```

But doing it the other way around seems much more complex.

How should I implement the custom converters for those 3 possible generics (string, int or double) ?

Comment: Could you use a nongeneric class ( with List<object>) for serialization/deserialization, and then make a conditional conversion to/from your generic business object?

Comment: I would say simple read the value always as string and post process it yourself into a concrete type. There is no guessing system in the serializer that tries to guess the type and instantiates the fitting type from it (If the type information is not hidden in the structure)

Comment: Looking here https://www.dicomstandard.org/dicomweb/dicom-json-format it seems that the `Value` items aren't always a primitive, sometimes they are complex objects.

Comment: @dbc, that's correct. This is the mechanism to allow nested structures.

Comment: How about a custom converter with logic in the read override- checks the type of the incoming value and then passes the value to the correct conversion method. `if (value is string stringValue) readStringValue(stringValue);`

Comment: You cannot deserialize it back to generic type. I mean, root type will not be generic (so - JsonSerializer.Deserialize<this one>). So you will deserialize to some kind of Dictionary<string, object> in which case - what's the point to have generics in the first place? You can deserialize it like that already - `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the System.Text deserializer, it will get you close if you supply what you are deserializing.  Try this:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, DataElement<object>>>(jsonString);
```

However if you use the NewtonSoft.Json deserializer, you will still want to let it know what you are expecting, but it will give you back the actual types for the numeric values; and the syntax looks like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DataElement<object>>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: This solution does not handle nested Dictionary.

Comment: What is a DataElement? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: user1034912, DataElement is defined in the initial question.

private class DataElement<T>
{
  public string vr { get; set; }
  public List<T> Value { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 2):

It is more complex, but doable. Try decoding them in order of int -> double -> string since a double cannot be an int and anything that is not an int or double should be a string.

```
var intval = 0;
var dblval = 0.0;

if (int.TryParse(value, out intval)
   return intval;

if (double.TryParse(value, out dblval)
   return dblval;

return value.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

> My goal is simply to load DICOM/JSON using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.

If that is the case then may I suggest you use NewtonSoft's Json converter. It's a lot easier to use and understand (even the Custom Converters).

Example:

### Initialize

```
var dataset = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataset.Add("00100021", new DataElement<string>() { vr = "LO", Value = new List<string>(1) { "Hospital A" } });
dataset.Add("00201206", new DataElement<int>() { vr = "IS", Value = new List<int>(1) { 4 } });
dataset.Add("00101030", new DataElement<double>() { vr = "DS", Value = new List<double>(1) { 72.5 } });
```

### Save

```
// Create a string for it
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(MyDictionary);
```

### Load

```
// Similar to your original object
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DataElement<object>>>(json);
```

### Test

```
foreach (var element in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element));
}
```

[image]

---

For additional info on custom converters see link below. But with your goal in mind I don't think a custom converter is required. Especially if you just want a `Dictionary<string, object>` out.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm

### Why NewtonSoft

I've had issues with the inbuilt JsonSerializer package converting `objects` to nulls, especially when networking.

Comment: You're trying to answer a question that was never asked. OP is **not** asking for alternative methods. OP explictly states, *"My goal is simply to load DICOM/JSON using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer"*